# VBA - Get Data From Multiple Internet Explorer tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I am tring to get credit ratings from sites like www.moodys.com and www.fitchratings.com .

At first my code works fine, it get the data I wanted from fitchratings.com then it changes the URL to www.moodys.com and get data from there, all is well. But when I want to open a new tab for the site www.moodys.com with CLng(2048) I get a run-time error '91'.

How can I fix this error?

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub AkbankNotGün_Click()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    'For Fitch
    IE.navigate "https://www.fitchratings.com/gws/en/esp/issr/80089736"

    Do         
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = IE.document
    Dim unot As String
    Dim knot As String
    Dim tarih As String
    Dim tkd As String

    tarih = doc.getElementsByClassName("rating_noborders")(1).innerText
    Range("B4").Value = tarih
    unot = doc.getElementsByClassName("rating")(0).innerText
    knot = doc.getElementsByClassName("rating")(1).innerText
    Range("D4").Value = unot & "/" & knot
    tkd = doc.getElementsByClassName("rating")(5).innerText
    Range("D5").Value = tkd


    'For Moody's
    IE.navigate "https://www.moodys.com/credit-ratings/Akbank-TAS-credit-rating-600017220", CLng(2048)

    Do         
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    tarih = doc.getElementsByClassName("dateValue")(0).innerText
    Range("F4").Value = tarih
    unot = doc.getElementsByClassName("link rating_link")(0).innerText
    Range("H4").Value = unot
    tkd = doc.getElementsByClassName("link rating_link")(12).innerText
    Range("H5").Value = tkd
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried using `navOpenInNewTab` ?

Comment: No I have not let me try,